# SQL use LAG to keep looking for value until criteria is met

Tags: sql, jinja2, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

Essentially I have what I call floating rows that come into my table. These are rows that have a `type = mod` and they are associated with a `customer_id`, but not another `transaction_id` in the table. I need them associated with another `transaction_id` and not just hanging out by themselves. So, I want to create a mapping table that gives the floating `transaction_id` values and the `previous_transaction_id` they are associated with. I'm using LAG to get the `previous_transaction_id` and that works for some scenarios, but not all. Essentially, I'd like to tell LAG - "Hey LAG, if the value you found is one of these floating `transaction_id` values, keep stepping back until you find one that isn't" But I don't know how to do that.

I'm using Snowflake and have jinja and dbt at my disposal if there is a better way to do this.

Here is some mock data with the various scenarios I have and my current query:

```
with data as (
select 
    transaction_id,
    customer_id,
    transaction_date,
    amount,
    type
from (values 
    (1, 'a','03/24/2022'::date, 10, 'cat'),
    (1, 'a','03/24/2022'::date, 15, 'dog'),
    (1, 'a','03/24/2022'::date, 20, 'mouse'),
    (1, 'a','03/24/2022'::date, 30, 'rabbit'),
    (1, 'a','03/24/2022'::date, 5, 'squirrel'),
    (2, 'a','03/24/2022'::date, 4, 'mod'), -- floater
    (3, 'b','05/20/2022'::date, 100, 'cat'),
    (3, 'b','05/20/2022'::date, 150, 'dog'),
    (3, 'b','05/20/2022'::date, 200, 'mouse'),
    (3, 'b','05/20/2022'::date, 300, 'rabbit'),
    (3, 'b','05/20/2022'::date, 50, 'squirrel'),
    (4, 'b','07/20/2022'::date, 40, 'mod'), -- floater
    (5, 'c','02/02/2020'::date, 100, 'cat'),
    (5, 'c','02/02/2020'::date, 150, 'dog'),
    (5, 'c','02/02/2020'::date, 200, 'mouse'),
    (5, 'c','02/02/2020'::date, 300, 'rabbit'),
    (6, 'c','08/01/2020'::date, 50, 'mod'), -- floater
    (7, 'c','12/25/2020'::date, 40, 'mod'), -- floater
    (8, 'd','01/15/2021'::date, 10, 'cat'),
    (8, 'd','01/15/2021'::date, 15, 'dog'),
    (8, 'd','01/15/2021'::date, 20, 'mouse'),
    (8, 'd','01/15/2021'::date, 30, 'rabbit'),
    (8, 'd','01/15/2021'::date, 5, 'squirrel'),
    (8, 'd','01/15/2021'::date, 4, 'mod'),
    (9, 'e','02/10/2020'::date, 100, 'cat'),
    (9, 'e','02/10/2020'::date, 150, 'dog'),
    (9, 'e','02/10/2020'::date, 200, 'mouse'),
    (9, 'e','02/10/2020'::date, 300, 'rabbit'),
    (10, 'e','08/17/2020'::date, 50, 'mod'), -- floater
    (11, 'e','12/15/2020'::date, 40, 'mod'), -- floater
    (12, 'e','02/14/2021'::date, 40, 'mod'), -- floater
    (13, 'c','04/09/2022'::date, 0, 'mouse'),
    (13, 'c','04/09/2022'::date, 0, 'rabbit'),
    (13, 'c','04/09/2022'::date, 50, 'mod') -- floater because other values for transaction_id sum to 0
    ) as tbl (transaction_id, customer_id, transaction_date, amount, type)
),
previous_transaction_id as (
select 
    transaction_id,
    customer_id,
    lag(transaction_id, 1, null) over (partition by customer_id order by transaction_date) as previous_transaction_id
from data
   qualify transaction_id != previous_transaction_id
),

floating_mods as (
    select 
        transaction_id,
        sum(iff(type = 'mod', amount, 0)) as mod_amount,
        sum(amount) - mod_amount as non_mod_amount
    from data
    group by 1
    having non_mod_amount = 0
)

select 
    gp.transaction_id,
    gp.previous_transaction_id
from previous_transaction_id gp
    inner join floating_mods fm on gp.transaction_id = fm.transaction_id
order by gp.transaction_id
```

And here is the output of the query:

| TRANSACTION_ID | PREVIOUS_TRANSACTION_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 7 | 6 |
| 10 | 9 |
| 11 | 10 |
| 12 | 11 |
| 13 | 7 |

And here is my desired output:

| TRANSACTION_ID | PREVIOUS_TRANSACTION_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 7 | 5 |
| 10 | 9 |
| 11 | 9 |
| 12 | 9 |
| 13 | 5 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is captures the rules precisely, but it should be close enough to tweak if necessary. The LAG function should ignore nulls, and you can specify what for the purpose of the LAG function you consider a null using the IFF function or CASE WHEN block.

```
with data as (
select 
    transaction_id,
    customer_id,
    transaction_date,
    amount,
    type
from (values 
    (1, 'a','03/24/2022'::date, 10, 'cat'),
    (1, 'a','03/24/2022'::date, 15, 'dog'),
    (1, 'a','03/24/2022'::date, 20, 'mouse'),
    (1, 'a','03/24/2022'::date, 30, 'rabbit'),
    (1, 'a','03/24/2022'::date, 5, 'squirrel'),
    (2, 'a','03/24/2022'::date, 4, 'mod'), -- floater
    (3, 'b','05/20/2022'::date, 100, 'cat'),
    (3, 'b','05/20/2022'::date, 150, 'dog'),
    (3, 'b','05/20/2022'::date, 200, 'mouse'),
    (3, 'b','05/20/2022'::date, 300, 'rabbit'),
    (3, 'b','05/20/2022'::date, 50, 'squirrel'),
    (4, 'b','07/20/2022'::date, 40, 'mod'), -- floater
    (5, 'c','02/02/2020'::date, 100, 'cat'),
    (5, 'c','02/02/2020'::date, 150, 'dog'),
    (5, 'c','02/02/2020'::date, 200, 'mouse'),
    (5, 'c','02/02/2020'::date, 300, 'rabbit'),
    (6, 'c','08/01/2020'::date, 50, 'mod'), -- floater
    (7, 'c','12/25/2020'::date, 40, 'mod'), -- floater
    (8, 'd','01/15/2021'::date, 10, 'cat'),
    (8, 'd','01/15/2021'::date, 15, 'dog'),
    (8, 'd','01/15/2021'::date, 20, 'mouse'),
    (8, 'd','01/15/2021'::date, 30, 'rabbit'),
    (8, 'd','01/15/2021'::date, 5, 'squirrel'),
    (8, 'd','01/15/2021'::date, 4, 'mod'),
    (9, 'e','02/10/2020'::date, 100, 'cat'),
    (9, 'e','02/10/2020'::date, 150, 'dog'),
    (9, 'e','02/10/2020'::date, 200, 'mouse'),
    (9, 'e','02/10/2020'::date, 300, 'rabbit'),
    (10, 'e','08/17/2020'::date, 50, 'mod'), -- floater
    (11, 'e','12/15/2020'::date, 40, 'mod'), -- floater
    (12, 'e','02/14/2021'::date, 40, 'mod'), -- floater
    (13, 'c','04/09/2022'::date, 0, 'mouse'),
    (13, 'c','04/09/2022'::date, 0, 'rabbit'),
    (13, 'c','04/09/2022'::date, 50, 'mod') -- floater because other values for transaction_id sum to 0
    ) as tbl (transaction_id, customer_id, transaction_date, amount, type)
), LAGGED as
(
select   TRANSACTION_ID
        ,TYPE
        ,lag(iff(type = 'mod' or AMOUNT = 0, null, TRANSACTION_ID)) ignore nulls over (order by TRANSACTION_ID) PREVIOUS_TRANSACTION_ID
from data
)
select TRANSACTION_ID, PREVIOUS_TRANSACTION_ID 
from LAGGED
where type = 'mod' and TRANSACTION_ID <> PREVIOUS_TRANSACTION_ID
;
```

| TRANSACTION_ID | PREVIOUS_TRANSACTION_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 7 | 5 |
| 10 | 9 |
| 11 | 9 |
| 12 | 9 |
| 13 | 9 |

Also, in the desired output the last row shows 5. Should that be 9?

Comment: Would LAST_VALUE also be useful in this scenario? See --https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74136511/repeat-the-previous-value-for-a-null-value-in-snowflake

Comment: Thanks for this solution! This was what I needed `lag(iff(type = 'mod' or AMOUNT = 0, null, TRANSACTION_ID)) ignore nulls`. The last row should be 5 because it is associated with customer c

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Greg, I was able to get what I needed:

```
with data as (
select 
    transaction_id,
    customer_id,
    transaction_date,
    amount,
    type
from (values 
    (1, 'a','03/24/2022'::date, 10, 'cat'),
    (1, 'a','03/24/2022'::date, 15, 'dog'),
    (1, 'a','03/24/2022'::date, 20, 'mouse'),
    (1, 'a','03/24/2022'::date, 30, 'rabbit'),
    (1, 'a','03/24/2022'::date, 5, 'squirrel'),
    (2, 'a','03/24/2022'::date, 4, 'mod'),
    (3, 'b','05/20/2022'::date, 100, 'cat'),
    (3, 'b','05/20/2022'::date, 150, 'dog'),
    (3, 'b','05/20/2022'::date, 200, 'mouse'),
    (3, 'b','05/20/2022'::date, 300, 'rabbit'),
    (3, 'b','05/20/2022'::date, 50, 'squirrel'),
    (4, 'b','07/20/2022'::date, 40, 'mod'),
    (5, 'c','02/02/2020'::date, 100, 'cat'),
    (5, 'c','02/02/2020'::date, 150, 'dog'),
    (5, 'c','02/02/2020'::date, 200, 'mouse'),
    (5, 'c','02/02/2020'::date, 300, 'rabbit'),
    (6, 'c','08/01/2020'::date, 50, 'mod'),
    (7, 'c','12/25/2020'::date, 40, 'mod'),
    (8, 'd','01/15/2021'::date, 10, 'cat'),
    (8, 'd','01/15/2021'::date, 15, 'dog'),
    (8, 'd','01/15/2021'::date, 20, 'mouse'),
    (8, 'd','01/15/2021'::date, 30, 'rabbit'),
    (8, 'd','01/15/2021'::date, 5, 'squirrel'),
    (8, 'd','01/15/2021'::date, 4, 'mod'),
    (9, 'e','02/10/2020'::date, 100, 'cat'),
    (9, 'e','02/10/2020'::date, 150, 'dog'),
    (9, 'e','02/10/2020'::date, 200, 'mouse'),
    (9, 'e','02/10/2020'::date, 300, 'rabbit'),
    (10, 'e','08/17/2020'::date, 50, 'mod'),
    (11, 'e','12/15/2020'::date, 40, 'mod'),
    (12, 'e','02/14/2021'::date, 40, 'mod'),
    (13, 'c','04/09/2022'::date, 0, 'mouse'),
    (13, 'c','04/09/2022'::date, 0, 'rabbit'),
    (13, 'c','04/09/2022'::date, 50, 'mod'),
    (14, 'c','05/09/2022'::date, 0, 'mod')
        ) as tbl (transaction_id, customer_id, transaction_date, amount, type)
),

floating_mods as (
    select 
        transaction_id,
        sum(iff(type = 'mod', amount, 0)) as mod_amount,
        sum(amount) - mod_amount as non_mod_amount
    from data
    group by 1
    having non_mod_amount = 0
),

previous_transaction_id as (
select 
    data.transaction_id,
    data.customer_id,
    lag(iff(floating_mods.transaction_id is not null, null, data.transaction_id), 1, null) ignore nulls over (partition by data.customer_id order by data.transaction_date) as previous_transaction_id
from data
    left join floating_mods on data.transaction_id = floating_mods.transaction_id
   qualify data.transaction_id != previous_transaction_id
)

select 
    gp.transaction_id,
    gp.previous_transaction_id
from previous_transaction_id gp
    inner join floating_mods fm on gp.transaction_id = fm.transaction_id
order by gp.transaction_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The example is quite complex, but as I understand it:

- You have a table where each record is a transaction
- A transaction can be paired with another transaction
- Not all transactions are paired
- You want to pair each unpaired transaction with the first *paired* transaction that comes before it
- Not every unpaired transaction is preceded by a paired one

We could restate the problem as "pair up each record with the last record before it that satisfies some condition". This is a join (with a predicate involving row numbers).

Rather than using a complex LAG query, I would approach this like so:

- Assign the row number to a column with [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html)
- Take only paired transactions with WHERE and put them into a CTE
- Take only unpaired transactions and put them into a CTE
- Match every unpaired row with every preceding paired row: `select unpaired.id as x, paired.id as y, paired.row_num as y_n ... from paired join unpaired on paired.row_num < unpaired.row_num`
- For each `x`, keep only the row with highest `y_n` [SQL: Get last row for each unique id](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45284017/19457060)

You mention jinja which is a Python templating framework. It is most useful for dynamically generating queries. I wouldn't attempt to use it for this, because your problem is easily solved with a static query. Dynamic generation would only add needless complexity.